# Lang Lemma 6.1 (before Sylow): if $p$ divides order of finite abelian group, then subgroup with $p$ order exists. Why is $x^s\neq1$ guaranteed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

**Lemma 6.1.** Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $m$, let $p$ be a prime number dividing $m$. Then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$.

It is clear to me that $|G|$ divides power of $n$ where $n$ is exponent of a group (this is by induction, take cyclic subgroup and use Lagrange theorem). It also clear that then $p \mid n$, so we can write $n=ps$.

However, I don't understand why we have an $x$ whose ***period*** is divisible by $p$ (smallest exponent). Of course we can put $y=x^s$ so we have $y$ with period $p$, but how do we know that $x^s\neq 1$?

My idea was to take the smallest exponent (period) of *a group* (every finite group has an exponent obviously) and apply first part of the lemma. However, that still doesn't guarantee that $x^s\neq1$.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, can someone enlighten me please?

PS: where would the argument fall if we use non-prime $m$ instead of prime $p$. Why in this case we cannot say there exists $x$ whose period is divisible by $m$?

Comment: Something obvious you are missing is that nothing you describe involves the *commutativity* of $G$. Unless you want to prove the lemma for all finite groups, commutative or not, you need to rely on something special about commutative groups.

Comment: Of course we rely on commutativity in the first part of lemma (the induction), because we need to construct a quotient group and each subgroup of abelian group is normal.

Comment: You say “Of course…” and then refer to a detail of the proof that was never mentioned in the question itself. Basically, your question is not self-contained. If you want your question to be answered only by people who have Lang’s book in front of them, leave things as they are. If you want the chance to get an answer from people who know that area of math but do not have Lang’s book (and which one — Algebra, Undergraduate Algebra,…? he wrote *many*  books) then edit your question to include more details of the proof of that lemma.

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. I have edited the question to include first part where order of G divides power of the exponent. Also, I have added additional question where we use nonprime $m$ instead of $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $p$ divides the exponent of $G$ (because $|G|$ divides a power of $n$ where $n$ is the exponent of $G$).  Therefore there exists an element $y$ whose order is divisible by $p$. From now on let $y$ be of order $p\times n_0$. Then $x=y^{n_0}$ is of order $p$ whence $\langle x\rangle$ is the subgroup you are looking for.

Edit : Let us prove that such $y$ exists. We do it by contradiction. Assume such $y$ does not exists, then for any $g\in G$ the order of $g$ is prime with $p$ (this where you need $p$ prime) and therefore the exponent of $G$ is also prime with $p$.

Comment: I don't understand **why** $y$ exists? Also, why cannot you say the same "argument" for arbitrary $n$ dividing exponent of G (no need to be prime)? Where do you use prime property, please explain.

Comment: @toxic I explained in the edit, the easiest way I see is to do it by contradiction.